# Yajra Datatable custom Model Attribute

Tags: laravel, datatables, yajra-datatable

I'm using Yajra Datatables for Laravel and it won't show the custom attribute for my User model. This is my User model:

```
protected $appends = ['sum_work_hours'];

public function work_hours()
{
    return $this->hasMany(WorkHour::class);
}

public function getSumWorkHoursAttribute()
{
    return $this->work_hours->sum('hours_total');
}
```

And this is in Controller:

```
public function showHours()
{
    return view('hour');
}

public function getHoursDatatable()
{
    $users = User::select(['name', 'email', 'sum_work_hours']);

    return Datatables::of($users)->make();
}
```

And in view:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">All Working Hours</div>

                <div class="panel-body">

                    <table id="users-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered">

                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Sum Work Hours</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>

                    </table>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#users-table').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/datatables/get_hours_datatable',
            columns: [
                { data: 'name' },
                { data: 'email' },
                { data: 'sum_work_hours' }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

And this is what I get:

[image]

What could be wrong?

Comment: This column 'sum_work_hours' doesn't exist in DB table and it's probably because of that... but how to fix this?

Comment: OK It seems to me that I have fixed it....but this query takes about 7 seconds to render the table...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was in my Controller

```
public function getHoursDatatable()
{
    // this line was wrong
    $users = User::select(['name', 'email', 'sum_work_hours']);

    return Datatables::of($users)->make();
}
```

It should have been like this:

```
$users = User::with('work_hours')->get();
```

Now I get the results in my table.

Comment: all custom attributes registered in the `$appends` array inside a Model will automatically be loaded as an attribute. so you can do `$appends = ['sum_work_hours'];` in your User Model.

Comment: I already did that and this is my next problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46027556/how-to-optimize-a-big-query