# How to optimize a big query?

Tags: laravel, datatables, yajra-datatable

I have a table with 10000 users and there is a relationship with `work_hours` table.

This is my User Model and how I get sum of work hours.

```
protected $appends = ['sum_work_hours'];

public function work_hours()
{
    return $this->hasMany(WorkHour::class);
}

public function getSumWorkHoursAttribute()
{
    return $this->work_hours->sum('hours_total');
}
```

And I made a query to show all users and their sum of work hours like this:

```
public function getHoursDatatable()
{
    $users = User::with('work_hours')->get();

    return Datatables::of($users)->make();
}
```

And this query takes about *7-8 seconds* to show the table which is very slow.

I know that this is because of summing up the total work hours from `work_hours` table for each user and I want to learn how to optimize this query if this is even possible considering the amount of data?

#### Update:

```
    $users = User::with('work_hours')->select(['users.name', 'users.email']);

    return Datatables::of($users)
        ->add_column('sum_work_hours', function(User $user) {
            return $user->work_hours->sum('hours_total');
        })
        ->make();
```

This gives me an error:

> DataTables warning: table id=users-table - Ajax error. For more
>   information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

#### Update 2

This works:

```
public function getHoursDatatable()
{
    $users = User::with('work_hours');

    return Datatables::of($users)
        ->addColumn('sum_work_hours', function(User $user) {
            return $user->work_hours->sum('hours_total');
        })
        ->make();
}
```

But also takes about *7-8 seconds* to load...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point your data will just get too big to query everything at once.

Basically you have 2 options:

1.
Since you already have 10K users (and that number might still grow?) I would suggest switching to async (`serverSide: true` option). You are using datatables, so obviously you do not need all 10K users in 1 page, nor do you need all of them for a single report.

Datatables do allow serverside processing and it does allow pagination, while keeping the options to filter and sort like you're probably doing right now.

The yajra package will keep doing what it is doing right now, the thing you will have to change is that you do not assign all users to the view and build it like that, you'll need an emtpy table and let the frontend populate it. Just create an api endpoint where you can point your datatable to, in order to fetch the paginated list from it.

So instead of using `@foreach ($users as $user)` in your view, do not fetch it in the controller action that displays the table, let the api endpoint handle it.

Example:

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Total Hours</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Total Hours</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

And you'll need to do this (here or in some lib you are using)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "../server_side/scripts/server_processing.php"
    } );
} );
```

You will also need:

//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js

If you did not already include that in your project, that's not clear from you info.

For more info see: [Datatables Server-side processing](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)

2.
Store the total sum of hours somewhere else. You could simply update the sum of hours per user when changes to the Workhour model are done. That way you will not need to do the sum every time you request a single or a list (or all) users.

My suggestion would be to do at least #1 and #2 will be a good optimization after that.

Comment: Do you have time for teamviewer to see this?

Comment: This is my previous question how I actually do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46027252/yajra-datatable-custom-model-attribute

Comment: Ah, that clears things up... Because you added the `get()` it now fetches all users, where before you just added the builder and you were able to paginate. The thing is that you request the column `sum_of_hours`, but it does not exist on the user table, you will need to add it manually. See https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/relationships

Comment: I get errors now with this: check my question update

Comment: Open up devtools and check the request and response, probably you have a column mismatch now because you changed the column names in your select.
For your second update, what is the output? All 10K or the paginated list with sums?

Comment: You should also consider installing debugbar and check which queries are being done and how long they take, that will get you in the right direction.

Comment: Yes i have debugbar, I get all the results paginated but it takes 7-8 seconds that is the only problem....can it be faster than that? After the table is rendered all is fast then...it searches and sorts instantly

Comment: So which query causes the slowness?

Comment: The query that sums the hours total for every user...that's the one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153574/discussion-between-lewis4u-and-robert).

Comment: proper indexes in place? If so, see #2 ^

Comment: The query that sums the hours total for every user...that's the one
because every user has many work hours....and in query they are summed up for each user and that takes along time...because the table is BIG
10K users and each has 30-40 inserts in work_hours table.....so 10K * 40 that is more than 400K calculations

Comment: How can i store the sum of hours

Comment: It should only sum the hours for the current page you are fetching

Comment: But why it doesn't that is the question

Comment: Lewis I would suggest a couple of things: 1) Check the actual query that is executed with the debug bar and do an Explain on it, now you can see whether indexes are used or not (see Robert's suggestion) 2) Are you fetching all 10000 rows? Why not pagination, then you get only 25 queries. 3) Google for 'eager loading, it will help. 4) select less columns